# bootstrap 4 navbar not squooshing when page is narrowed

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm so novice I'm not even sure of the terms and definitions.

All was working well, but I clearly broke something.

When I narrow the page completely, it is fine. When I expand completely, it is fine. But a few stages in between, the navbar dropdowns exceed the container and fly out to the right.

I did not alter any of the @media parameter that were prefabbed in this dreamweaver set up.

```css
.nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #FFCC00!important;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.nav-link:hover, .nav-link:focus {
    color: #33ccff!important;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link.disabled {
  color: #6c757d;
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}

.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-item {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover, .nav-tabs .nav-link:focus {
  border-color: #e9ecef #e9ecef #dee2e6;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.disabled {
  color: #6c757d;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active,
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #dee2e6 #dee2e6 #fff;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.nav-fill .nav-item {
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-justified .nav-item {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-content > .tab-pane {
  display: none;
}

.tab-content > .active {
  display: block;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

.navbar .container,
.navbar .container-fluid, .navbar .container-sm, .navbar .container-md, .navbar .container-lg, .navbar .container-xl {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar-custom {
    background-color: #0a0a0a;
}
/* change the brand and text color */

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand,
.navbar-custom .navbar-text {
    color: rgba(243, 203, 4, 1);
}
/* change the link color */
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
/* change the color of active or hovered links */
.navbar-custom .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-custom .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: #33ccff;
}
.navbar-brand {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: inherit;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navbar-brand:hover, .navbar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
}

.navbar-text {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler {
   color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   border-color: #f3cb06;
   background-color: #0A0A0A;
    text-align: center
} 

.custom-toggler .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(243,203,6,1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

/*change toggler color*/

.custom-toggler.navbar-toggler {
    border-color: #ffcc00;
    text-align: center;
}
    
/*end change toggler color but I need to change the toggler bg color*/

.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover, .navbar-toggler:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: "";
  background: no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```

```html
 <div class="container-align align-content-center">
     
      <div class="container align-content-center"><img src="images/CDBanner.png" alt="" width="100%" class="img-fluid" lass="img-fluid"/></div>
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="container-fluid">
    
    <div class="container">
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-custom navbar-custom">
    
    
    
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg custom-toggler" style="background-color: rgb(10, 10, 10);">  
    
    
    
    <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a> </li>
        
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Posters</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">QI Posters</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Case Studies Posters</a>
            
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Booklets &amp;&nbsp; Brochures</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Booklets</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Brochures</a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Logos &amp; Illustrative</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logos</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Illustrative</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Motion</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Motion 1</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Motion 2</a>
            
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Motion 3</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Motion 4</a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown5" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Social Media</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Before &amp; After Ads</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">FaceBook &amp; Instragram</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">YouTube Thumbnails</a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown6" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Other&nbsp; </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Other</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Web Site and UI</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">T-Shirts</a></div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
    </div>
```

I have been trying to center this navbar. It was centered [navigation flying out to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VLhn.png)at one time and I don't know where that went.

But this is not coded the way the bootstrap site advises. I think I'm unwilling to redo it.

[navigation expanded beyond container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VLhn.png)

Comment: When you use Bootstrap, you don't have to write your own CSS except for override something based on Bootstrap. About the HTML, you can start from copy HTML and class from [their document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) to see that it is working then start to modify for your own.